# Why doesn't Django enforce my unique_together constraint as a form.ValidationError instead of throwing an exception?

Tags: django, validation, django-forms, modelform

*Edit: While this post is a duplicate of [Django's ModelForm unique_together validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141030/djangos-modelform-unique-together-validation), the accepted answer here of removing the 'exclude' from the ModelForm is a much cleaner solution than the accepted answer in the other question.*

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4025968/why-is-self-instance-not-set-in-clean-function-for-a-bound-form).

If I don't explicitly check the unique_together constraint in the clean_title() function, django throws an exception:

> **IntegrityError at /journal/journal/4**
>
> duplicate key value violates unique constraint "journal_journal_owner_id_key"
>
> Request Method: POST
>
> Request URL:   http://localhost:8000/journal/journal/4
>
> Exception Type:    IntegrityError
>
> Exception Value:   duplicate key value violates unique constraint "journal_journal_owner_id_key"
>
> Exception Location:    /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py in execute, line 19

However I was under the impression that Django would enforce this constraint nicely by raising a ValidationError, not with an exception I need to catch.

Below is my code with an additional clean_title() method I use as a work-around. But I want to know what I'm doing wrong such that django is not enforcing the constraint in the expected manner.

Thanks.

Model code:

```
class Journal (models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='journals')
    title = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=256)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("owner", "title")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Form code:

```
class JournalForm (ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Journal
        exclude = ('owner',)

    html_input = forms.CharField(label=u'Journal Content:', widget=TinyMCE(attrs={'cols':'85', 'rows':'40'}, ), )

    def clean_title(self):
        title = self.cleaned_data['title']
        if self.instance.id:
            if models.Journal.objects.filter(owner=self.instance.owner, title=title).exclude(id=self.instance.id).count() > 0:
               raise forms.ValidationError(u'You already have a Journal with that title. Please change your title so it is unique.')
        else:
            if models.Journal.objects.filter(owner=self.instance.owner, title=title).count() > 0:
               raise forms.ValidationError(u'You already have a Journal with that title. Please change your title so it is unique.')
        return title
```

View Code:

```
def journal (request, id=''):
    if not request.user.is_active:
        return _handle_login(request)
    owner = request.user
    try:
        if request.method == 'GET':
            if '' == id:
                form = forms.JournalForm(instance=owner)
                return shortcuts.render_to_response('journal/Journal.html', { 'form':form, })
            journal = models.Journal.objects.get(id=id)
            if request.user.id != journal.owner.id:
                return http.HttpResponseForbidden('<h1>Access denied</h1>')
            data = {
                'title' : journal.title,
                'html_input' : _journal_fields_to_HTML(journal.id),
                'published' : journal.published
            }
            form = forms.JournalForm(data, instance=journal)
            return shortcuts.render_to_response('journal/Journal.html', { 'form':form, })
        elif request.method == 'POST':
            if LOGIN_FORM_KEY in request.POST:
                return _handle_login(request)
            else:
                if '' == id:
                    journal = models.Journal()
                    journal.owner = owner
                else:
                    journal = models.Journal.objects.get(id=id)
                form = forms.JournalForm(data=request.POST, instance=journal)
                if form.is_valid():
                    journal.owner = owner
                    journal.title = form.cleaned_data['title']
                    journal.published = form.cleaned_data['published']
                    journal.save()
                    if _HTML_to_journal_fields(journal, form.cleaned_data['html_input']):
                        html_memo = "Save successful."
                    else:
                        html_memo = "Unable to save Journal."
                    return shortcuts.render_to_response('journal/Journal.html', { 'form':form, 'saved':html_memo})
                else:
                    return shortcuts.render_to_response('journal/Journal.html', { 'form':form })
        return http.HttpResponseNotAllowed(['GET', 'POST'])
    except models.Journal.DoesNotExist:
        return http.HttpResponseNotFound('<h1>Requested journal not found</h1>')
```

**UPDATE WORKING CODE:**
*Thanks to Daniel Roseman.*

Model code stays the same as above.

Form code - remove exclude statement and clean_title function:

```
class JournalForm (ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Journal

    html_input = forms.CharField(label=u'Journal Content:', widget=TinyMCE(attrs={'cols':'85', 'rows':'40'},),)
```

View Code - add custom uniqueness error message:

```
def journal (request, id=''):
    if not request.user.is_active:
        return _handle_login(request)
    try:
        if '' != id:
            journal = models.Journal.objects.get(id=id)
            if request.user.id != journal.owner.id:
                return http.HttpResponseForbidden('<h1>Access denied</h1>')
        if request.method == 'GET':
            if '' == id:
                form = forms.JournalForm()
            else:
                form = forms.JournalForm(initial={'html_input':_journal_fields_to_HTML(journal.id)},instance=journal)
            return shortcuts.render_to_response('journal/Journal.html', { 'form':form, })
        elif request.method == 'POST':
            if LOGIN_FORM_KEY in request.POST:
                return _handle_login(request)
            data = request.POST.copy()
            data['owner'] = request.user.id
            if '' == id:
                form = forms.JournalForm(data)
            else:
                form = forms.JournalForm(data, instance=journal)
            if form.is_valid():
                journal = form.save()
                if _HTML_to_journal_fields(journal, form.cleaned_data['html_input']):
                    html_memo = "Save successful."
                else:
                    html_memo = "Unable to save Journal."
                return shortcuts.render_to_response('journal/Journal.html', { 'form':form, 'saved':html_memo})
            else:
                if form.unique_error_message:
                    err_message = u'You already have a Lab Journal with that title. Please change your title so it is unique.'
                else:
                    err_message = form.errors
                return shortcuts.render_to_response('journal/Journal.html', { 'form':form, 'error_message':err_message})
        return http.HttpResponseNotAllowed(['GET', 'POST'])
    except models.Journal.DoesNotExist:
        return http.HttpResponseNotFound('<h1>Requested journal not found</h1>')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django's ModelForm unique\_together validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141030/djangos-modelform-unique-together-validation)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The trouble is that you're specifically excluding one of the fields involved in the unique check, and Django won't run the check in this circumstance - see the `_get_unique_checks` method in line 722 of `django.db.models.base`.

Instead of excluding the `owner` field, I would consider just leaving it out of the template and setting the value explicitly on the data you're passing in on instantiation:

```
 data = request.POST.copy()
 data['owner'] = request.user.id
 form = JournalForm(data, instance=journal)
```

Note that you're not really using the power of the modelform here. You don't need to explicitly set the data dictionary on the initial GET - and, in fact, you *shouldn't* pass a `data` parameter there, as it triggers validation: if you need to pass in values that are different to the instance's, you should use `initial` instead. But most of the time, just passing `instance` is enough.

And, on POST, again you don't need to set the values explicitly: you can just do:

```
journal = form.save()
```

which will update the instance correctly and return it.

Comment: Thanks, that all makes sense. One thing about setting the data dictionary on the initial get - each journal has a one-to-many relationship with the content. On save I parse the HTML returned and break it into chunks and save those. On load (GET) I "reconstitute" those chunks into a single HTML block. Is there a more Django-native or "Pythonic" way to define this data transformation to leverage the ModelForm?

Comment: Btw this problem is reported as django bug 13091 https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13091

Answer (score 2):

I think the philosophy here is that unique_together is an ORM concept, not a property of a form.  If you want to enforce unique_together for a particular form, you can write your own clean method, which is easy, straightforward, and very flexible:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other

This will replace the clean_title method you have written.

Comment: Except that only one of the unique_together fields, title, is editable. The other is basically private - it's the foreign key linking a journal to the current user. So from that perspective I should keep the validation in the clean_title() since it's the only form field I'm validating, right?

Comment: I see.  In that case, you might try a ComboField? http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ComboField